# java meaning of expression, if else condition shortcuts

Tags: java, syntax

What does  `head = head + 1 == array.length ? 0 : head +1;` mean?
Does `?` means if(condition)  and `:` means else? Can someone write out this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a ternary operator that is used as an if-else statement.
The basic syntax of the ternary operation is:

```
x = (Condition)?(value if true):(value if false);
```

For example,

```
String x = (2>5)?"2 is greater":"5 is greater";
```

In the above example, the output will be "5 is greater"

In your example,

```
head = head + 1 == array.length ? 0 : head +1;
```

It can be written as,

```
if ((head + 1) == array.length) {
        head = 0;
    } else {
        head = head + 1;
    }
```